# i do not understand why my code render twice - simple React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

simple and silly code, but for some reason the console.log("hi") happens twice. i tried to create the usual todo-list project but my program double clicked everything, so i texted and reached this point - this code execute any JS a the render method - twice.

anyone knows why?

```
    import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log("hi")}
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It depends on how many times you use the App Component. Try to check it.

Comment: onces inside index.js -  i did not even open up the index.js file meanning it was left just as installed.

Answer (score 1):

Re-rendering happened some time. In many cases it’s not a problem, but if the slowdown is noticeable, you can override the lifecycle function **shouldComponentUpdate**, which is triggered before the re-rendering process starts. If you know that in some situations your component doesn’t need to update, you can return false from **shouldComponentUpdate** instead, to skip the whole rendering process, including calling render() on this component and below.

In most cases, instead of writing shouldComponentUpdate() by hand, you can inherit from **React.PureComponent**. It is equivalent to implementing **shouldComponentUpdate()** with a shallow comparison of current and previous props and state.

Here is an example found from [reacjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html)

**Example**

```
class CounterButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: 1};
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.color !== nextProps.color) {
      return true;
    }
    if (this.state.count !== nextState.count) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        color={this.props.color}
        onClick={() => this.setState(state => ({count: state.count + 1}))}>
        Count: {this.state.count}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i did found the solution you are refering to few days back, though i still dont understand under which conditions the render() method deside to ... well... rerender.

i would love to understand how it works, is there anywhere i can find the original documentation of react folder?